# Play locally cached youtube video

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, video, youtube, cache

I have recently watched a Youtube video and have found out that Chrome stores temporary files in `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache`. However, all files there are without a valid format. Is it possible to retrieve a cached video and play it offline? If so, what is the format in which Chrome caches Youtube videos?

Comment: Are they FLV format?

Comment: No, all cached files are format-less.

Comment: Possible dupe: [I played an online video in html5 player on google chrome, where is it stored on my local storage?](//superuser.com/q/828072)

Comment: I have tried the steps in the answer of that post, but it did not work for me.